# How to get selected tab line in BottomNavigationView like in TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to show a line under selected tab in `BottomNavigationView` just like in `TabLayout`, but so far I am not able to find any solution.

**BottomNavigationView**

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAshWhite"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAshWhite"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_nav"/>
```

**TabLayout**

[image: TabLayout Sample]

Comment: The material version of `BottomNavigationView` isn't really designed to do that. See: https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html

Comment: yes you are right but its just that requirements are like that so I am looking for a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I have a dirty hack for that,

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.firstItem:
                    underlineSelectedItem(bottomNavigationView, R.id.firstItem);
                    break;
return false;
        }
    });
```

Use this method,

```
private void underlineSelectedItem(BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView, int selectedID) {

    for (int i = 0; i < bottomNavigationView.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        MenuItem menuItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i);
        menuItem.setTitle(menuItem.getTitle().toString().replaceAll("[<u>/]", ""));
    }
    MenuItem menuItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(selectedID);
    String currentText = (String) menuItem.getTitle();
    String convertedText = "<u>" + currentText + "</u>";
    menuItem.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(convertedText));
}
```

I know this is somewhat ugly, but i think there's no other way to do it.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear about it but its not text that I want to underline, but the tab

Comment: This is the only thing you can do